MS Office Word 2013 - Table cell with weird spacing between words

In the image i have a weird situation in Microsoft Word 2013.
There is a simple, basic table. You are looking at a snippet of one of the cells, which has a weird spacing between letters i cannot seem to get rid of, no matter what !
The Font menu - Spacing is useless, it wont register!
yes, the table is fully editable!
Any ideas ?
Also, i tried "Remove formatting” and suddenly, all writing in that cell vanished!
After removing formatting, i can no longer write in that cell - however, all others work just fine!
Also ...whats with the weird blue underline ?!  I didnt make that!
That cyan underline ?!
